# Maven 2 Archetype creation: how to concatenate variables in folder/file names

Tags: xml, maven, maven-archetype

I want, from my archetype, to create an xml file which name has two variables concatenated together.

Example:
archetype-metadata.xml

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="category"/>
    <requiredProperty key="description"/>
</requiredProperties>
```

Given category="MyCategory" and description="MyDescription", I want my file to be named "MyCateogryMyDescription.xml". Not "MyCategory-MyDescription.xml" nor anything else with something between the two.

The reason behind this weird, specific, inflexible requirement is, well, obviously backward compatibility with standards I don't want to touch.

My first try was the obvious __category____description__.xml, but it turns out that the generated file is named "MyCategory__description__.xml". If I add something between them, like a dash as __category__-__description__.xml it resolves correctly to "MyCategory-MyDescription.xml", but that's not what I want as I said before.

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. Have you meanwhile found a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't worked out a solution yet but the problem is in the Maven Archetype code - they use a regular expression of '__.*__' which is greedy and loses any leading underscores. The regex should be rewritten to replace the .* with 'not underscores', something like '__^[_]__'. But someone submitted a fix like this many years ago and it never made it into the main release. I'm going to go try the composition approach below now and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could define an additional *requiredProperty*, which default value corresponds to the combination of the *description* and *category* tags values (i.e. accessible by means of the usual ${...} notation).

Therefore, considering the above cited example, you could insert the following snippet in the *archetype-metadata.xml* file

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="category"/>
    <requiredProperty key="description"/>
    <requiredProperty key="categoryDescriptionComposition">
        <defaultValue>${category}${description}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

and finally name your file as *__categoryDescriptionComposition__.xml*.

Comment: thanks! sorry for the old reply, I somehow figured it out long ago as you may suppose. I should really have answered this before...